# C++ macros to ensure used memory is freed?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, macros

So I am a bit of a n00b and was reading about `new`, `delete`, and pointers, and I am certain that I will forget too many deletes over the course of my life.  So I was wondering if a macro like the following would be more trouble than it's worth.

```
#define withObject(ptr, value, BODY)                       \
{                                                           \
     ptr = value;                                           \
     BODY                                                   \
     delete ptr;                                            \ 
     ptr=NULL                                               \
}
```

Would this macro cause some problems or behave in an unexpected way?

Edit: oops I left off the d on freed.  Well thanks everyone for the answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, do not do this. It won't prevent either memory leaks or stray pointers. Instead, read up on smart pointers. The current standard provides one in the shape of [auto_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/auto_ptr/), but many more (and better ones) are available, depending on your C++ platform.

Also, I suspect you may be over-using new and delete - they should be used very rarely in your code. You should prefer to use values. So instead of something like this:

```
string * s = new string ( "foobar" );
....
delete s;
```

you should simply write:

```
string s( "foobar" );
```

and have the compiler manage the lifetime of the string for you.

Comment: @Martin sorry, I don't believe in allowing editing of answers, except to remove dangerous errors, misspellings, and in the case of CW, of course.

Comment: @unapersson: From [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your questions and answers being edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you."

Comment: @Brian I am comfortable with it, as my comment suggested, but not if it changes the sense or thrust of my answer.

Comment: @unapersson: with all due respect, suggesting auto_ptr is just plain wrong. I hope you know why.

Comment: @rubenvb: no one is suggesting auto_ptr. He's suggesting **smart pointers**. One obvious benefit of auto_ptr is the standard. The other is, that it will subtly _force_ you to realize that a smart-pointer is **never** a true pointer

Comment: @rubenvb If you mean because it will be deprecated in the next standard, well the next standard is not with us yet, and we have to work with the C++ platforms we have at the moment. And what did you take me to mean with "many more (and better ones)"? Also, despite deprecation, auto_ptr will join that long list of deprecated things that never actually get removed from standards.

Comment: Using smart pointers should also be somewhat rare.  The Standard Template Library (or Boost, if you're allowed to use it) will usually have code to handle dynamically created objects.

Comment: @Brian The only feature of the current C++ Standard Library that manages objects dynamically created by the user is std::auto_ptr. I'm not clear what you are saying here.

Comment: @rubenvb: auto_ptr is really very useful. The programmer just needs to understand its quirks. It's a lot better than manual delete.

Comment: @unapersson: my point is that suggesting `std::auto_ptr` as the simple solution to this *very* general problem is not right. And I don't know where you have been living for the past years, but 1) As far as everyone who won't pay for a C++ Standard document is concerned, [c++11 is as final as it gets](http://herbsutter.com/2011/03/25/we-have-fdis-trip-report-march-2011-c-standards-meeting/), 2) All major compilers have implemented smart pointers, 3) [boost can always be used](http://www.boost.org/users/license.html), except in homework/embedded situations, 4) RAII, which you mentioned, loosely.

Comment: @unapersson: `Vector` allows you to create a collection of objects using memory dynamically.  This allows for dynamic memory management.  Without the STL, you could accomplish this by using a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: @rubenvb I did not suggest auto_ptr as a solution to the general problem. If you could be bothered to read my answer, you will see that I suggested using smart pointers. And I have paid for my C++ Standards documents, thank you.

Comment: @unapersson: yeah, OK, I may have overreacted. I still stand by my point to bury `auto_ptr` in the deepest pit you can dig. I never suggested you're a cheapskate, just tried to say colourfully the new Standard is quite finished, but not quite.

Answer (score 8):

No need to reinvent the wheel here, you are looking for [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

The very useful [Boost](http://www.boost.org) library has [smart pointer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) functionality.

Answer (score 4):

google [RAII idiom](http://www.hackcraft.net/raii/); it is the same but not so hacky; you can then apply this on your dynamic allocations using the ubiquitous smartpointers (which automatically free memory when they go out of use/scope).

Boost contains the most famous/widespread version of a smart pointers (seveal flavours).

The C++ standard has always had a kind of crippled smart pointer, named `auto_ptr`. This is one with caveats but useful in it's own right (RTFM!).

C++0x adopts several of the Boost TR1 classes, including the most popular smart pointer (I hope I'm wording this right because the standardese is usually quite specific on details)

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the *smart pointer* pattern. It's standard C++ and explained in detail at [this site](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html).

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that you really should use smart pointers (even the lowly `auto_ptr` will serve for your purpose), there's possible problems with BODY.  Using a potentially large section of code as an argument for a function-like macro has its own traps.  For example, if there's an unparenthesized comma in BODY, then BODY turns to two arguments.  I'm not sure of further issues, because I've never seen anybody try it.

Don't use function-like macros in C++.  It's rarely worth it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you wish to allocate an object, do a short piece of work on it, then delete it. For this purpose I would suggest std::auto_ptr.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic C++ way to do this sort of thing is not with macros, but with "smart pointer" classes that use [Resource Acquisition is Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).  For instance, Boost's [scoped_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) would work nicely in the contexts where your macro would make sense.

I'll put a sketch of a smart pointer class here - but I'm leaving out a lot of details.  This is just to give you an idea of how they work.  Use scoped_ptr instead, they didn't leave anything out.

```
template <typename T>
class smartptr<T> {
public:
    smartptr() : ptr(new T) {}
    smartptr(T* p) : ptr(p) {}
    ~smartptr() { delete ptr }
    T& operator*() { return *ptr; }
    T* operator->() { return ptr; }
private:
    T* ptr;
}
```

Comment: It is so dangerous to leave **broken code** like that for beginners. They will not realize how dangerous it is. If you can't provide the full implementation then don't show the code.

Comment: Implementing your own smart pointer is like implementing your own PRNG or encryption - almost always a bad idea. They are REALLY difficult to get right.

Comment: I think code to demonstrate what's going on under the hood is valuable, and I think mine leaves so much out that it won't trip anyone up because it won't actually be usable except for toy scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

> Would this macro cause some problems or behave in an unexpected way?

If BODY throws an exception then the `delete` will be skipped.

The solution is to make use of the "RAII" idiom. It's one of the most important concepts in modern C++  programming.

Answer (score -2):

I think a better solution would make an allocate and delete macro instead of an all-inclusive. Thats a really messy, not very helpful thing to do

When I program in C I commonly do something like the following:

```
#define ALLOC_ARY(type, sz) (type*)calloc(sz, sizeof(type))
#define ALLOC_STR(sz) ALLOC_ARY(char, sz)

char *string = ALLOC_STR(128);
int *array = ALLOC_ARY(int, 20);
```

But remembering to free in vanilla C is just part of it:

```
free(string); string = NULL;
free(array); array = NULL;
```

**Edit:** For C++, smart pointers as others have suggested are a good way to go.